# Grep unknown number of spaces (linux)

Tags: regex, grep

Suppose you have a file named abc.txt - the file contains 2 (or generally more) lines:

```
word  -c           (09:35:20)
word     -c        (09:38:49)
```

If you run the command `$ grep "word  -c" abc.txt` you get only the 1st line, because the number of spaces between 1 and -c does not match the 2nd line.  Is there a way to fix this problem?

You cannot use `grep'word1|word2' /path/to/file` as the spaces between word and -c vary.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `+` regex character, which will match at least one of the preceding character:

```bash
grep -E "word +-c" abc.txt
```

This regex reads "match 'word', followed by one or more spaces, followed by '-c'."

Comment: What you mean "grabbing the right files"? Will you please show us an example together with an expected output?

Comment: I mean like grabbing all strings that say "word" followed by unknown number of spaces (nothing else) and then "-c"

Comment: @user2619315 Try with the `-E` switch (I've amended my answer).  Some greps require this to interpret an unescaped `+` as a metacharacter.

Answer (score 3):

grep 'word *-c' abc.txt will work. I couldn't get grep 'word +-c' abc.txt to work.

Comment: maybe you need egrep, or grep -E then.

Answer (score 2):

you can use egrep with regex

```bash
egrep "word\s+-c" abc.txt
```

or

```bash
egrep "word +-c" abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep 'word \+-c' abc.txt`

Use single, not double, quotes.  "+" signifies "one or more of the preceding expression, so would find any number of spaces (except zero).

Here's a reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | egrep -v "^[[:space:]]?+#" | grep -v "^$"
```

this will remove any line that starts with `#` or any spaces before a `#`